# History in own C Shell

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm writing my own C Shell and I'm having trouble implementing something to maintain a history of commands.
I'd like to store it in a struct with an integer and string (so I can keep the command and its place in memory together), and I only want to store 20 elements.

I've tried using code from questions other people have asked on this website but when I compile it, it just returns a segmentation fault, so I'm guessing there's something wrong with the pointers.

Here's all the code I found relating to the history:

```
char** cmdHistory; /* command history - no longer than 20 elements & null terminated */
int historySize = 0;

void addToHistory(char* newEntry) {
    char** h;
    int historySize = 0;
    while (*cmdHistory != NULL) 
    if (sizeof(cmdHistory) == 20) {
        char** newPtr = ++cmdHistory;
        free(cmdHistory[0]);
        cmdHistory = newPtr;
        h = (char**)realloc(cmdHistory,20*sizeof(int));
        cmdHistory = h;
        cmdHistory[20] = newEntry;
    } else {
        h = (char**)realloc(cmdHistory,sizeof(int)+sizeof(cmdHistory));
        cmdHistory = h;
        cmdHistory[historySize] = newEntry;
        ++historySize;
    }
    }

void printHistory() {
    char** currCmd = cmdHistory;
    printf("\n\n");
    while (*currCmd != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", *currCmd);
        currCmd++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main() {
    cmdHistory[20] = NULL; /* null terminate the history */
}
```

I'm pretty useless with C, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "I'm writing my own C shell"  Do you mean you are writing a bourne shell in C, or a C shell?  If the latter...why?

Comment: Use libreadline, it keeps history automatically and provides support for custom completion.

Comment: The code is quite strange. For example, I'm not sure why you'd realloc the table because you add a new element if the table is supposed to have a fixed size. The whole thing looks mighty suspicious to me, and wherever you found the bits of code you're using, I'd look somewhere else. As to why it segfaults, you define cmdHistory as a char** pointer and as the first thing, without initializing it, in main you set "cmdHistory[20] = NULL;" Before you do cmdHistory[20], cmdHistory needs to be initialized and allocated. There's also no point in null-terminating an array with a known length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use link list to implement history, always adding present command at the head. Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct history
{
    char *ent;
    struct history * next;
}hist;

hist *top = NULL;

void add(char *s)
{
    hist *h =  (hist *) malloc(sizeof(hist));
    h->ent = s;
    h->next = top;
    top = h;
}

void print()
{
    hist *i;
    for (i = top; i != NULL; i = i->next)
        printf("%s\n", i->ent);
}

int main()
{
    add("command");
    print();
}
```